# npm install not working. Says that I need to check permissions?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install eslint on my machine right now but it is saying that I need to check permissions because its missing write access to /user/local/lib/node_modules. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

```
npm install -g eslint
```

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mkaplan/.npm/_logs/2019-03-03T18_05_46_487Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try it with sudo npm install -g eslint

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try `sudo npm install -g eslint`

Comment: Thanks that worked! Should have guessed to just sudo it.

Comment: your'e a legend. Thank you!!

Comment: This will allow you to install eslint, but I don't think you need to sudo if npm is installed correctly. (And running sudo here is probably a security risk, as some people have pointed out below.)

Comment: This is only a temporary fix and not a solution. You're most likely an admin of your machine and you probably mistakenly installed node and npm as a root, which now owns npm related stuff. Simply uninstall npm and don't ever use `sudo` to install it.

Answer (score 3):

For Linux use `sudo npm install` and
For Window run powerShell as administrator and got to directory of project and run `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had this same problem to install angular, so just change the command to :

```
$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

This can solve the problem:

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This kind of stuff happens when you run npm commands with sudo to begin with. So don't do it?

If this happens, it means that someone has been messing around npm as root. Then root took and created files in global npm cache, denying access to anything different than root.

This is why it fires `EACCES` when running `npm install` or `npm install -g`

You are not supposed to do anything related to `node_modules` nor run`npm [anything]` with `sudo`. Do you understand that you are giving the package in question permission to do whatever it wants? Even if you check the package and ensure its security yourself, what about dependencies it downloads? will you check them as well?

`npm registry` gets 30b weekly downloads, their malware control is nowhere near enough

You are giving away access to whole sys folder tree to the files of the package in question. Even npm itself gives you feedback that it is not recommended. You do not know what package does in the background. What if you install a package i developed, but i am a villian who likes to make people's life harder... This is a security issue.

The above story apart. If you do it with sudo, this will force you to run certain npm commands as sudo from that point on, messing it up even more.

The maximum you do as root in this case, is give access for `node_modules` to `whoami`

The best solution is to either set it up properly so you dont have to use sudo or run app in container, so anything you do is executed inside container, not affecting your local machine at least. Even there it is not recommended to mess around as root, permissions get so messy... it's a hell to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to Node but as a longtime Linux user I'not sure installing node packages as root (via sudo) is a good idea.

I imagine eslint is fine but if you're having this issue installing one package then I'm guessing you're having the same problem with every package you're installing globally ('-g'). That means that every time you install a package from npm globally you're downloading who-knows-what install script and running it with root privileges on your computer.

Anyway, as I said I'm no Node expert but I had this same problem and my issue was that I'd installed the "nodejs" package using apt. If this is what you did then I suggest:

1. Remove nodejs with `sudo apt remove nodejs`. (Depending on what Linux distro you're using this may be different. I'm running Ubuntu.)
2. Install [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or some other node version manager as recommended by [the NPM docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm).

When I did this, I was able to install NPM packages globally without `sudo`.

(Yes, I'm telling you not to install things by running `npm` as root and then saying you should install things by running `apt` as root. But you definitely need to run apt as root and I know appropriate precautions are taken by the apt devs and Ubuntu package repo managers. I'm not 100% sure it's wrong to run npm as root but I'm not sure it's right either, and I was able to avoid running it as root using the above steps.)

Answer (score 0):

First try    `sudo npm install -g gatsby-cli`
then    `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue trying to install truffle and got the following errors:
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user

I was able to solve this issue with the recommendation to add 'sudo'.
solution:
sudo npm i -g truffle

Answer (score 0):

Use the command:

`sudo npm install -g eslint`

With the sudo command you will have the permission to install.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when you just "sudo" everything in order to make it work or you install a dependency forcefully , you should not mess with the root folder of node modules.
For now you can try installing using

```
sudo npm install -g eslint
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm config get prefix`

Then run this:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}`

Enter the password and run installation commands.

It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Use this `npm install node-sass --save`