# nodemon package is not install in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

`nodemon` package does not successfully install using nodejs. I used `npm install -g nodmon`. I received the permissions-related error below.

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js' -> '/usr/bin/nodemon'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js' -> '/usr/bin/nodemon']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js' -> '/usr/bin/nodemon'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!      path: '../lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js',
npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/bin/nodemon' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'../lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js\' -> \'/usr/bin/nodemon\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/bin/nodemon' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/etech7/.npm/_logs/2019-07-02T11_31_52_856Z-debug.log
```

Comment: maybe try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972076/npm-install-not-working-says-that-i-need-to-check-permissions

Comment: I would install [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). Node Version Manager manages your global packages so they all reside in your home directory which means you don't have to use `sudo` to install them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to install it with sudo. It it because you need admin permissions.

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes Dr. Cooper you are right It it  need admin permissions in linux.

I was try use below command and it work it.

sudo npm install -g nodemon

Comment: yes thanks Dr.Cooper. I'm using Mac OS and this works for me much thans

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue, as indicated by the error message. You need to fix your permissions or use `sudo`. Please see: [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)